# Pearson correlation on two categorical variables

Tags: correlation, binary, one-hot-encoding, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

I am using the fourth-corner method in one of my papers (for those who need the name). The method was developed to test associations between variables in two datasets. In my case, the datasets contains traits of species (e.g. trait Size with modalities 'small', 'medium', 'large'). The method recognizes the data type and then apply appropriate statistics.

The correct cases:

1. If two variables are quantitative, the fourthcorner calculates Pearson correlations.
2. If two variables are qualitative, factorial, the method calculates a Chi2.
3. If the variables are mix, it calculates a Pseudo-F test.

However, in my study and a study I criticize, we had to convert factorial data into categorical binary data.
In my case, instead of having ONE trait column containing small, medium, large, I have 3 columns, small, medium, large coded as factors **yes** or **no**.
In that other study, they coded as 0/1. If coded as 0/1, the data is first standardized.

If categorical and coded as  0/1 instead of factorial (e.g. biological traits of species, coded as presence/absence 0/1), the method will calculate Pearson correlations instead of Chi2. Or actually, "will return Pearson correlations" if wrongly specified in the output. Which is what they did and analyze in the study.

I am trying to **justify why this is wrong**, why you should use categorical data coded as yes-no and do a Chi2, but I am not entirely sure how to explain it, or justify how correlations calculated from the 0/1 do not mean what one thinks.

If we have two categorical variables, height and weight, split in class such as:

height: short, medium, tall (0/1)

weight: thin, large (0/1)

To my understanding:
When you calculate correlation between short and thin, you calculate correlations of being short/not short, with thin/not thin as the variables are non-dichotomous.

How would you justify that?

Tables look like this:

for their data

| Short | Medium | Tall |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

| Thin | Large |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

for my data

| Short | Medium | Tall |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no | yes | no |
| yes | no | no |
| no | no | yes |

| Thin | Large |
| --- | --- |
| no | yes |
| no | yes |
| yes | no |

Best,

Comment: I personaly fail to fully understand the question. I would benefit if an example of both cases (ie correct and incorrect application of algorithm) is presented

Comment: @NikosM. Ok I will try to explain it. The paper I am referring to is Spitz et al. 2014
doi: 10.1111/1365-2656.12218

Comment: @NikosM. I added  more details. Is it better?

Comment: So The problem is when categorical variables are one-hot-encoded and then associated with chi2 test. This would lead to wrong results

Comment: Not sure what one-hot-encoded means but the problem is when categorical variables are coded as 0/1 and the method calculate a correlation on that. All variables are categorical 0/1, and some are not dichotomous.
The correct procedure should be to calculation the frequencies of observation and use a Chi2. Interpreting correlations based on categorical 0/1 leads to wrong interpretations.

Comment: In every scenario, it is still a Categorical variable and Chi/Crammer's V should be used. Interpretation will change a bit if we have OHE(0/1) encoded features. Height Vs Weight will become 6 pairs of Correlation.

Comment: [One Hot Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)

Comment: @NikosM. I did not know the term. I call it "binary coding". But that's exactly that.

Comment: @10xAI Could you direct me to a paper I could use to justify that?
I do agree Correlation is not appropriate but not sure what literature I can use to justify it (nor why reviewers did let that slide).

Comment: [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-one-hot-encoding-your-categorical-variables-bbb0fba89809) makes some points on why one-hot-encoding is not the best choice, maybe start there

Comment: see [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9) as well

Comment: Finally [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-multicollinearity-and-the-dummy-variable-trap-b5840be3c41a) also seems useful for your case

Comment: In essense, one-hot-encoding (or one-cold-encoding) of categorical variables apart from increasing dimensonality , it also introduces multi-colinearity in the supposed independent features which leads to various problems